# COUNT(field) return 0 if it doesn't exist

Tags: sql, ms-access

Sounds like a simple thing to do, but I'm struggling with it and probably over thinking it.

I'm basically trying to figure out if a `category`, and what `category` that is, that is missing a `Job` value in the `title` field... and I'm trying to do it without iteration.

So in this example, it should return something indicating that `Strategy` doesn't have a `Job` in the `title` field.

My initial though was to just do a `COUNT()` like in the following example:

```
SELECT category, COUNT(title)
FROM grid_mgmt
WHERE title = 'Job'
GROUP BY category;
```

But then that became apparent it wouldn't work because there isn't anything to count.

Any suggestions on how to return a 0 if there is nothing to count, or perhaps a better way of tackling this issue in MS Access with SQL?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT category, SUM(IIF(title = "Job", 1, 0))
FROM grid_mgmt
GROUP BY category;
```

Or if you have a separate category table, a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select c.category, count(gm.category)
from category as c left join
     grid_mgmt as gm
     on gm.category = c.category and
        gm.title = "Job"
group by c.category;
```

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56158868/3123109) answered the question, but wanted to expand on it since I eventually modified it to just return those that `= 0`:

```
SELECT category
FROM (
  SELECT category, SUM(IIF(title = "Job", 1, 0)) AS count
  FROM grid_mgmt
  GROUP BY category
)
WHERE count = 0;
```

Just in case this helps someone else down the road.